# Firebase REST API login verification format error?

Tags: firebase, rest, authentication

I am using Firebase Email authentication REST API to login to my app.

### I want to know if the email is verified or not.

I referred https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-confirm-email-verification

I got the rest URL `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=[API_KEY]`

the given URL also take a payload as `oobCode` , the output of `post` request 
should be a JSON object with a field `emailVerified`.

now my main goal is to know `emailVerified` boolean field, the given REST URL 
does not take any other information like whose email to check if it is verified or what is his access_token, I don't want to provide addition VERIFICATION_CODE as I sent a verification link, not the code.

Is there a very to know if the given URL is verified or not with REST API?

Answer (score 0):

There is a JSON  response payload of user info containing `emailVerified` field as well.
see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-get-account-info

use `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=[API_KEY]` endpoint.